# How to pass multiple values from models.py to HTML via views.py in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a following **models.py** for my Django blog, I made a following **views.py** to pass the value of the slug for my URL parameter.
However I am struggling to create a model in views to get other data(person & description) from Category class.
I have tried some patterns by myself but can not pass them to HTML. (always Error or not showing)
Can you please give me some idea of how to solve this.

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    person = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.person
```

**views.py**

```
def blog_category(request, category):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(categories__slug__contains=category).order_by("-created_on").distinct()
    context = {"category": category, "posts": posts}

    return render(request, "blog_category.html", context)
```

**HTML(Localhost:8000/slug)**

```
{{ person }}
{{ description }}
```

this is full code of my models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    person = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.person


class Recommender(models.Model):
    recommender_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.recommender_name


class Post(models.Model):
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    book_link = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    recommenders = models.ForeignKey("Recommender", on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    source = models.TextField()
    source_link = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    categories = models.ManyToManyField("Category", related_name="posts")

    slug = models.SlugField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_title
```

Comment: Can you also show your `Post` model class?

Comment: @ArunT I have updated my question. I tried what you deleted before asking here but nothing was showing.

Comment: I read your question two fast and hence miss-read the name of your model class. Give me a moment I shall give you the right approach

Comment: I have updated the answer, since u are using manytomany field, you will have one more list inside Post.categories, so you will need two for loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(categories__slug__contains=category).order_by("-created_on").distinct()
```

Is going to return a queryset. It can have more than one instance of the model class (since you are using `filter`). In your context you are sending this queryset as `posts` to your templates.

So in your HTML you can use something like this. You need to use a for loop since there can be more than one item in `posts`.

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% for category in post.categories.all %}
        {{ category.person }}
        {{ category.description }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you man, but this gives me another Error 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable. I will find out the way to fix.

Comment: Oops i forgot, just change     `{% for category in post.categories %}` to     `{% for category in post.categories.all %}`

Comment: Also, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271339/access-many-to-many-field-within-django-template)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is working perfectly. Allow me to ask one more question please. Is there any way that I can get the value from person & description without using for loop? You do not need to give a coding but I just want to know if there is any way to do that.

Comment: It would be nice to use `prefetch_related` here to improve performance and prevent queries in the loop to the database from the template. Please check it in Django docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Comment: @trey_0329 In that case, are you looking at just getting the first value? Since it is many to many field, the idea is that there can be more than one category for a particular post. So either you need to use a for loop, or you need to choose any one in a hard coded way, such as first or last or something.

_Do accept the answer in case it helped you so that its easier for the next person_

Comment: @AleksandrSuvorov yeah, good idea to reduce no of queries run in db.

Comment: Thank you guys, I have learned a lot. Really appreciate your supports

Answer (score 0):

I would look at [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something).

Namely, if you render the template like it is shown in the example, you should be able to do

```
{{ category.person }} {{ category.description }}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will refer to the link.